# How to call a test script from another test script in watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using watir to create automation suite.
I have mutlitple test scripts file and structure of my test script is like:

```
require_relative 'RubyDriver'
require 'test/unit' 

class LoginTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

def test_method
    @driver = RubyDriver.new("/home/pratik/study/UIAutomation/LoginScript.xlsx")
    @driver.call_driver
end

def teardown
       @driver.create_report
       puts "[Finishing at #{Time.now}]\n\n"
    end

    def setup
       puts "[Starting at #{Time.now}]\n\n"
    end
   end
```

Now say i have to automate 2 flows which is 1. login and create booking 2. login and cancel booking

i will have similar script for create booking and cancel booking, but how would i make it as a test case:
1. login,create booking
2. login,cancel booking

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create modules with your steps in as separated methods and mixin or include it in TestCase class you want to compose.

You could use method_defined? to create a hook for calling mixed methods and call it.

Comment: Thanks Romain. I shall give this a try

Answer (score 0):

I currently have 58 watir-webdriver tests and the way I run them all at once is using a bat script to call each one after the previous has finished.

This method will only work on windows however since it's a bat file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Working on ubuntu. Moreover I wanted to call one script into another